# Escape array elements before join

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array which have special characters in its elements. Lets say array_1 like this:

```
array_1 = %w(a b c d' e")
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d'", "e\""]
```

I am joining them in later parts of the code. Like:

```
array_1.join(",")
#=> "a,b,c,d',e\""
```

Printing that string results in:

```
a,b,c,d',e"
```

Now, I need to pass the above string in a java script function as a string itself. Basically by wrapping it up in single quotes. Like:

```
'a,b,c,d',e"'
```

Which is where it fails. Thoughts.

Comment: Can't you just escape the single quotes?

array1.collect{ |c| c.gsub(/'/, "\'") }.join(',')

Comment: What would be the correct string for your JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
%w(a' b c").map { |e| e.gsub /'|"/, '' }
```

work for you?

Comment: @tobmath. Nope, It did not.

What I tried: 

`logger.info(array_1.join("', '"))`

`array_1.map { |e| e.gsub /'|"/, '' }`

`logger.info(array1_join(","))`

Both logger statements gave me same thing i.e. `a,b,c,d',e"`

Comment: The example above does not modify the array itself, so if you are calling `.map { |e| e.gsub /'|"/, '' }` the content of array1 does *not* change. Use Array#map! instead, or `array1 = array1.map { |e| e.gsub /'|"/, '' }`

Comment: @tobmath. My bad. I should have noticed it myself. Anyway, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: This removes the quote marks, it doesn't escape them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-inspect). It returns the string enclosed in quote marks with special characters escaped:

```
puts "someJavaScriptFunction(#{array_1.join(',').inspect});"
```

Output:

```
someJavaScriptFunction("a,b,c,d',e\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to remove single and double quote will do the job. Check below code.

```
array_1 = %w(a b c d' e") # your array
str = array_1.join(",")
str.gsub!(/\'|\"/, "") 
puts str # "a,b,c,d,e"
```